# does go ++ operator need mutex?

Tags: go

Does go ++ Operator need mutex?
It seems that when not using mutex i am losing some data , but by logic ++ just add +1 value to the current value , so even if the order is incorrect still a total of 1000 run should happen no?
Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    i := 0
    for r := 0; r < 1000; r++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            i++
            fmt.Println(i)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("%d Done", i)
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the program? What did you expect to happen? What is the actual and expected output? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "try it and see" is difficult at the best of times (see questions about `null` is SQL, integer division, ... for examples of reasoning from specific cases going wrong) and nearly impossible with concurrency issues. That's why we like to have language specs.

Answer (score 2):

To "just add 1 to the current value" the computer needs to *read* the current value, add 1, and *write* the new value back. Clearly ordering does matter; the standard example is:

```
Thread A     Thread B
Read: 5
             Read: 5
+1 = 6
             +1 = 6
Write: 6
             Write: 6
```

The value started at 5, two threads of execution each added one, and the result is 6 (when it should be 7), because B's read occurred before A's write.

But there's a more important misconception at play here: many people think that in the case of a race, the code will either read the old value, or it will read the new value. *This is not guaranteed*. It might be what happens most of the time. It might be what happens all the time *on your computer*, with the current version of the compiler, etc. But [actually it's possible](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) for code that accesses data in an unsafe/racy manner to produce *any* result, even complete garbage. There's no guarantee that the value you read from a variable corresponds to any value it has *ever* had, if you cause a race.

Answer (score 0):

> just add +1 value to the current value

No, it's not "just add". It's

1. Read current value
2. Compute new value (based on what was read) and write it

See how this can break with multiple concurrent actors?

If you want atomic increments, check out [sync/atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/). Examples: https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters